# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Tags: pdo

I can't get the following PDO statement to work

```
<?php
    // Update (Edit) user details in DB

    // DB Connection include
    include_once('connstring.inc.php');
    //include_once('key.inc.php'); // Not necessary for update as UID is already generated

    $User_ID = $_POST['user_id'];
    $First_Name = ucfirst($_POST['first_name']);
    $Last_Name = ucfirst($_POST['last_name']);
    $Address = $_POST['address'];
    $Phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $District = ucfirst($_POST['district']);
    $State = ucfirst($_POST['state']);
    $Country = ucfirst($_POST['country']);
    $Pin_Code = $_POST['pin_code'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $User_Name = $_POST['user_name'];
    //$UID = $_POST['UID'];
    $Admin_Group = $_POST['admin_group'];
    $Admin_Status = $_POST['admin_status'];

    // Update DB with new values
    $sql = "UPDATE admin_user SET first_name = :firstname, last_name = :lastname, address=  :address, phone = :phone, district = :district, state = :state, country =     :country,pin_code = :pincode, email = :email, user_name = :username, admin_group =    :admingroup, admin_status = :adminstatus WHERE user_id = :userid";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':firstname'=>$First_Name, ':lastname'=>$Last_Name,  ':address'=>$Address, ':phone'=>$Phone, ':district'=>$District,':state'=>$State,':country'=>$Country,':pincode'=>$Pin_Code,':email' >$Email,':username'=>$User_Name,':admingroup'=>$Admin_Group,':admin_status'=>$Admin_Status, :userid'=>$User_ID));
    $conn = null;
    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
?>

My MySQL table structure is as follows:
======================================
    (DB Name:admin_user)

    user_id
        first_name
        last_name
        address
        phone
        district
            state
        country
            pin_code
        email
        user_name
        password
        UID
        admin_group
        admin_status
```

I am using the current version of the jQuery jtable plugin. Inserts are working fine in the same table. But on trying to update I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]:  Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /var/www/test.com/public_html/admin/adminedituser.php:28\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/test.com/public_html/admin/adminedituser.php(28): PDOStatement->execute(Array)\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/test.com/public_html/admin/adminedituser.php on line 28

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have read most of the comments for similar error at stackoverflow and re-checked and re-checked but unable to locate the error.

Comment: Remove parameters one by one till the error is gone

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice..Located the error:). The error was in the line:     ':admin_status'=>$Admin_Status, should have been :adminstatus and not :admin_status...One thing that defies my logic was that I was trying reading line by line and unable to locate it....Thank you once again for the advice to remove parameters one by one..unfortunately it was the last one..:)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    /* 
     * Update (Edit) user details in DB
     * DB Connection include
     */
    include_once('connstring.inc.php'); 

    $user_info_arr = [];
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
    {
        $user_info_arr[$key] = $val;
    }

    //update DB with new values
    $query = "UPDATE `admin_user` SET 
                                  `first_name`      = :firstname, 
                                  `last_name`       = :lastname, 
                                  `address`         = :address, 
                                  `phone`           = :phone, 
                                  `district`        = :district, 
                                  `state`           = :state, 
                                  `country`         = :country,
                                  `pin_code`        = :pincode, 
                                  `email`           = :email, 
                                  `user_name`       = :username, 
                                  `admin_group`     = :admingroup, 
                                  `admin_status`    = :adminstatus 
                              WHERE 
                                  `user_id` = :userid";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(
            array(
                ':firstname'    =>  ucfirst($user_info_arr['first_name']), 
                ':lastname'     =>  ucfirst($user_info_arr['last_name']),  
                ':address'      =>  $user_info_arr['address'], 
                ':phone'        =>  $user_info_arr['phone'], 
                ':district'     =>  ucfirst($user_info_arr['district']),
                ':state'        =>  ucfirst($user_info_arr['state']),
                ':country'      =>  ucfirst($user_info_arr['country']),
                ':pincode'      =>  $user_info_arr['pin_code'],
                ':email'        =>  $user_info_arr['email'],
                ':username'     =>  $user_info_arr['user_name'],
                ':admingroup'   =>  $user_info_arr['admin_group'],
                ':adminstatus'  =>  $user_info_arr['admin_status'], 
                ':userid'       =>  $user_info_arr['user_id']
            )
    );

    $conn = null;

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = [];
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
?>
```

It also took me to cleanup your code. And really using $_POST and passing to an individual variable is pretty ugly; instead use an array...

Try to check if it works now.